Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false
When I try to use Gerrit trigger in Jenkins, the problem as shown in the title occurs and the connection attempt fails. The specific error is as follows:
Jul 03, 2024 6:38:16 PM SEVERE com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection connect
Could not connect to Gerrit server! Host: 192.168.10.25 Port: 10005
Jul 03, 2024 6:38:16 PM SEVERE com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection connect
 Proxy: 
Jul 03, 2024 6:38:16 PM SEVERE com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection connect
 User: admin KeyFile: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/jenkins
Jul 03, 2024 6:38:16 PM SEVERE com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection connect
IOException: 
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:347)
    at com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.ssh.SshConnectionImpl.connect(SshConnectionImpl.java:196)
Caused: com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.ssh.SshException
    at com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.ssh.SshConnectionImpl.connect(SshConnectionImpl.java:200)
    at com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.ssh.SshConnectionFactory.getConnection(SshConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.ssh.SshConnectionFactory.getConnection(SshConnectionFactory.java:117)
    at com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection.connect(GerritConnection.java:498)
    at com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritConnection.run(GerritConnection.java:404)

But when I specify the ssh key file to try to connect, it is successful:

I hope someone can help me, thanks!!

In Java11 ed25519 keys do not work, maybe that's the issue. What Java version does your Jenkins use? What kind of key do you have?
